# symfony2 fresh installation test : app_dev.php works but app.php get redirection. Why prod doesn't work?

Tags: symfony

I installed latest symfony2 and follow the book to install and setup everything.

Xampp is in /opt/lampp, 
symfony2 is in my home dir ~/proj/symfony2.

I made a symbol link  /opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony2 => ~/proj/symfony2.

In browser, I type in "localhost/symfony2/web/app_dev.php". It works! the page shows up.

But if I used app.php instead, browser will be redirected to /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.

If I copy app_dev.php to app.php, still doesn't work!!! Why this happens?

If I copy app_dev.php to app_test.php and use "localhost/symfony2/web/app_test.php". It works!

I really don't know why it is so hard to make prod work in symfony2.

I read a lot of post about app.php get 404 error. And try clear, warmup, dump....nothing help.

I know acmedemo is for debug only. But how to test prod out of box? I do this because I follow book to write a acme hello but didn't work in prod. I put it to app_dev.php, didn't work.

app/prod.log: could be the reason?

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /bundles/framework/images/input_bg.gif"" at
>   /.../symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php
>   line 94 [] []

Answer (score 3):

The Symfony2 Standard Edition comes with a complete demo that lives inside a bundle called AcmeDemoBundle.

This bundle available only for dev environment:

AppKernel.php

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
```

routing_dev.yml:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

You should:

1) remove the AcmeDemoBundle
http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/bundles/remove.html

2) generating a new bundle 
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/routing.html

Comment: Try to do from beginning and setup virtual host done. But when I access the symfony2/web, it gives me:.htaccess: DirectoryIndex not allowed here from /log/lampp/logs/

Answer (score 0):

Setup virtual host seems works for access app.php or app_dev.php

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs" 
    ServerName localhost 
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log" 
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName myweb.local
    ServerPath "/home/xxx/proj/myweb/symfony2/web"
    ServerAlias www.myweb.local

    UseCanonicalName Off
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    DocumentRoot "/home/xxx/proj/myweb/symfony2/web"
    <Directory /home/xxx/proj/myweb/symfony2/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all 
        #AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
         #Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require local
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/myweb.local-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/myweb.local-access_log" common
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to `dump()` function, I have prod env issues resolved by remove dump in few files (like repository files).

You can either check your apache configuration.